# Is it true that $((p\land q \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is this a sound inference rule?

$$((p \land q) \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$$

So far I've rewritten it to 
$$((p \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$$

It looks similar to the syllogism rule, but I'm not sure. Any help?

Comment: $(p\to r)\land\neg(p\to r)$ is a contradiction. The usual proof laws allow you to infer anything whatever from a contradiction.

Comment: $((p\land q)\to r)\land \lnot(p\to r) \equiv (p\to (q\to r)) \land \lnot(p\to r)$ which is not equivalent to $((p → r) ∧ ¬(p → r))$.

Comment: Can you do truth tables?

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, do you have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 1):

@GEdgar's suggestion was spot on.  If you write a truth tabe to consider $2^3 = 8$ possible truth-value assignments for $(p, q, r)$, you will see that your given expression is, in fact, a tautology, meaning that no matter what truth values you assign to $p, q$ and $r$, the propostion will always be true:

[image]

Hence, indeed, the implication is a valid and sound inference rule.

Comment: Is this possible to prove using some rules of inferences?

Comment: By "rules of inference" do you mean something like a natural deduction proof, or do you mean something more like using identities to rewrite the expression until you get T?

Comment: @DanielSchepler, I was thinking about if there is possible to rewrite the expression into something fitting any of these rules https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/ql-cache/quicklatex.com-f5c9f79a6b74253cae5762709170cb47_l3.svg

Comment: @user635758 The "rules of inference" column there definitely looks in the spirit of natural deduction, I can write out an answer using a system I'm more familiar with if you like.

Comment: This is weird. I mean, yes, it is a tautology; and I can even verify from first principles that you cannot make the implication false. But I still balk at it; it seems to say that if two things imply a third and the first by itself does not, then the second by itself *does*. But I keep thinking about situations in which two statements imply a third in conjunction, but neither of them does by itself. E.g., $p=“a\leq b”$, $q=“a\neq b”$, $r=“a\lt b”$. Certainly, $a\leq b\land a\neq b\rightarrow a\lt b$, and $\neg(a\leq b \rightarrow a\lt b)$, but $\neg (a\neq b\rightarrow a\lt b)$.

Comment: Of course, the reason is that the statements I have above have implied universal quantifications. In any specific assignments, the whole implication *does* work...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The fact that $(p \land q) \rightarrow r \Leftrightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \lor (q \rightarrow r)$ is one of my favorite [Paradoxes of Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication), showing that the material conditional is not a perfect capture of the English conditional.  For a concrete example, I use: "If you are male and unmarried, then you are a bachelor" ... so .... ?!?!??!

Answer (score 0):

Not using your rules of inference, but mine...

[ 1]TO PROVE $((p \land q) \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$
[ 2]$\quad$ ASSUME $((p \land q) \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)$
[ 3]$\quad$ TO PROVE $q \rightarrow r$
[ 4]$\qquad$ ASSUME $q$
[ 5]$\qquad$ TO PROVE $r$
[ 6]$\qquad\qquad$ $\lnot(p \rightarrow r)\qquad$ by [2]
[ 7]$\qquad\qquad$ $\lnot(\lnot p \lor r)\qquad$ by [6], definition of $\rightarrow$
[ 8]$\qquad\qquad$ $p \land \lnot r\qquad$ by [7],  DeMorgan
[ 9]$\qquad\qquad$ $p\qquad$ by [8]
[10]$\qquad\qquad$ $p \land q\qquad$ by [9],[4]
[11]$\qquad\qquad$ $(p\land q)\rightarrow r\qquad$ by [2]
[12]$\qquad\qquad$ $r\qquad$ by [11],[10], modus ponens, establishes [5]
[13]$\qquad$ $q\rightarrow r\qquad$ by [4]...[12], establishes [3]
[14]$ $ $((p \rightarrow r) \land \lnot(p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$, by [2]...[13], establishes [1]